# Bitwise left shift in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have submitted a code snippet shown below:

```
def shift():
    m = 8
    low = '10100111'
    lw = int(low, 2)
    lw = lw << 1
    l_bin = bin(lw)[2:].zfill(m)
```

Output ==> 101001110(9-bits)

while desired output ==> 01001110(8-bits)

I could understand that right shifting the `lw` variable causes the integer value to shift from 167 to 334. But I want the output to be the desired output.

Comment: So why don't you just slice it to 8 characters? `l_bin= l_bin[-8:]`

Comment: @Rawing slicing is an option but increases code length

Comment: Note, you can start with binary literals if you are worried about code length: `lw = 0b10100111`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the low variable is not in original code ....I was debugging an error in code where lw was shifted to left by 1 bit keeping bit representation constant at 'm' specified bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to mask the upper bits if you want to emulate a byte (like it would behave in C):

```
lw = (lw<<1) & 0xFF
```

Of course, that is, if you keep `m` set to 8 or it won't work.

If `m` varies, you can compute (or pre-compute) the mask value like this:

```
mask_value = 2**m-1
lw=(lw<<1) & mask_value
```

(The aim of all this is to prefer arithmetic operations to string operations which are more CPU/memory intensive.)